# SmartTable Excel Download Date format issue

Tags: sapui5

I'm using sap.ui.comp.smarttable.SmartTable for displaying data in table. I was able to display Dates in Date format by using CustomData.

In View for displaying date in table, used below:

```html
<Column width="100px">
 <customData>
  <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "ExemptEndDt", "maxLength": "5","columnIndex":"33", "leadingProperty": "ExemptEndDt"}' />
 </customData>    
 <Label text="{i18n>ExemptEndDt}" design="Bold" tooltip="{i18n>ExemptEndDt}" />
</Column>
```

But when I'm downloading data in Excel, it is showing data in json date format

/Date(1451606400000)/

I was able to show date format by using the onBeforeExport event, by passing type as Edm.Date type. This way, I was able to display json date as Date in MM/dd/yyyy format.
But my requirement is to show date as dd/MM/yyyy. 
I understand that I need to use inputFormat property, but I could not figureout how to pass the property as my required data.

Can anyone please suggest on the format I need to use..

The SmartTable is using Spreadsheet for achieving this https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.export.Spreadsheet/constructor

In controller, I changed type of the date column to Edm.Date type as below:

```js
  onBeforeExport: function (oEvt) {
   var mExcelSettings = oEvt.getParameter("exportSettings");
   mExcelSettings.workbook.columns[33].type = sap.ui.export.EdmType.Date; //ExemptToDate
   mExcelSettings.workbook.columns[33].width = 10;
   mExcelSettings.workbook.columns[32].inputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //Not Working
   
   // GW export
   if (mExcelSettings.url) {
    return;
   }
  },
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your code as **formatted** code instead of (links to) images.

Comment: Added the code snippet. Can you pls check..

Answer (score 0):

You could've achieved this format ('03.09.2020  0:00:00') by adding edmType property to customData in a view like this:

```
<core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "Period", "columnIndex":"4", 
"edmType":"Edm.DateTime", ..}'/>
```

It's from John Patterson's comment in post [New Excel export functionality available](https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/23/new-excel-export-functionality-available/)

In my case following solution let export to excel Dates without time: "14.09.2020":

```
<table:AnalyticalColumn leadingProperty="someProp">
    <Label text="{some binding}"/>
    <table:customData>
        <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{ "columnKey": "someProp", "columnIndex" : "18", "type":"date"}'/>
    </table:customData>
    <table:template>
    [some template]
    </table:template>
</table:AnalyticalColumn>
```